# Recursion to normal loop convert

Tags: java, recursion

I have a method that is actually counting someValues.The Method is given below.

```
public static double sum(int z, int x, int y)
    {
        double count = 0.0;
        if (x == 0)
        {
            if (z <= 0) return 1.0;
            return 0.0;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= y; i++)
        {
            count += sum(z - i, x - 1, y);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

I just want to convert this method from recursion to normal iteration. Or if possible to some one line equation. Please help me.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output ?

Comment: sure .. sum(2,2,4)=16,sum(4,1,4)=1

Comment: This is a tricky question, With z <= x the answer is y^x, but with growing z the result gets smaller.

Comment: I don't see any attempt on your part to do this after the research you've done on the topic.  Hint: your termination condition (base case) depends entirely on **x** (although the return value depends on **z**).  Thus, you remove the recursion with an outer loop that iterates through all values from the original **x** down to 0.

Comment: @Prune it's not so easy i think, with every call spawning y children you get some kind of pascal triangle

Comment: @Prune i guess its a complex one. I tried bt I failed.

Comment: @fafl: That's why you get a nested loop as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is not pretty, but it works without recursion. Also i changed the return type from double to int because of reasons:

```
public static int sum(int z, int x, int y)
{
    // Compute number of calls
    int[][] calls = new int[x+1][x*y+1];
    calls[0][0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= x*y; j++) {
            for (int target = j+1; target <= j+y && target <= x*y; target++) {
                calls[i+1][target] += calls[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Return count of last column where z <= 0
    int result = 0;
    for (int j = x*y; z-j <= 0; j--) {
        result += calls[x][j];
    }
    return result;
}
```

To understand, have a look at this high-tech Excel sheet:

[image: Call stack visualisation]

This chart illustrates a call of `sum(3, 3, 3)`. Horizontally you see x and vertically you see z both get smaller. y is 3 and not changed.

The top left `1` means one call to `sum(3, 3, 3)`. This call then spawns three child calls (because of y=3): `sum(2, 2, 3)`, `sum(1, 2, 3)` and `sum(0, 2, 3)`. These three calls are found in the next column (where x=2).

Each of those three calls then spawns again three calls, shown in the row of x=1. These nine calls overlap a bit regarding z. Each of those nine calls then spawns again three calls, resulting in 27 calls in the x=0 column.

To get the result, you simply count all calls in the x=0 column, where z <= 0. In this example this is every call, so you get a result of 27. For a larger z the result would be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double sum(int z, int x, int y) {
    int num = 0;    
    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        if (z - x - i > 0) {
            num++;
        }
    }

    return (double) (Math.pow(y, x) - num);
}
```

Explanation: your method launches at most `y^x` recursive calls. On the last level of recursion, where `x == 0`, you have to determine the max value of `z` throughout all the calls and check how many of these calls do have `z > 0`, so that the call returns 0 and you do not have to take it into account. Now, on the last level of recursion, the max value of `z` is given by `z - x`. You now simply count all the instances in the `for` loop for which `z - x` stays positive so it does not influence your sum. After you computed that number, substract it from the initial approximation of the result, which was `y^x`.

Comment: This gives 79 for sum(6, 4, 3), where the correct result is 76